# Android getIntent() can't find my String

Tags: string, android-intent, get

I have a usual Intent from one activity to an other and give the second activity the path to the file needed.

```
Activity one:
private void onFileClick(int position)
{
    File file =new File(folder+ "/"+ getListAdapter().getItem(position).toString());

    Intent i = new Intent(this, (Activity two).class);
Log.e("Given File",file.toString());
i.putExtra(file.toString(), key);
startActivity(i);
}

Activity two:

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Intent i = getIntent();
String filepath = i.getStringExtra((Activity One).key); //Returns null
File parseFile = new File(filepath); //NullpointerExeption
}
```

Have i initialized the intent wrong?

Comment: So apparently the first argument in putExtra() is the key and not the value. This question can be deleted if a mod wants to